# How to incorporate blog into asp.net 3.5 MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, blogs

I want to have a blog feature in my website.Website is built using .net 3.5 MVC with fluent Nhibernate.Don't want anything fancy, just something which lets me post content and can provide archives and grouping of content

Comment: You should have a look at http://subtextproject.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) for existing solutions that you can use or adapt for your needs.  For example, might be interested in [Oxite](http://oxite.codeplex.com/) as solution or inspiration.